# How does RichTextBox jump to texttrange in wpf

Tags: wpf

When there is a lot of content on the page, the retrieval content may not be in the current window. I hope to jump to the page where the retrieval content is located. At present, the retrieval is done by textrange. I hope to jump to the past according to textrange. My English is not good,Please help me，Here is my code

```
    string searchStr = "";
    List<TextRange> textRanges = new List<TextRange>();
    int currentPoint, oldCurrentPoint;
    internal void findContent(string text, RichTextBox richtextbox, bool diretion)
    {
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return;           
        if (textRanges.Count != 0) textRanges[oldCurrentPoint].ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent);
        if (searchStr != text)
        {
            textRanges = FindTextInRange(richtextbox.Document.ContentStart, richtextbox.Document.ContentEnd, text);
            currentPoint = 0;
            oldCurrentPoint = 0;
            searchStr = text;
        }
        if (textRanges.Count == 0) return;
        oldCurrentPoint = currentPoint;
        if (diretion)
        {
            currentPoint++;
            if (currentPoint > textRanges.Count - 1) currentPoint = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPoint--;
            if (currentPoint < 0) currentPoint = textRanges.Count - 1;
        }

        textRanges[oldCurrentPoint].ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent);
        textRanges[currentPoint].ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x49, 0x3e, 0x8c)));
    }

    public List<TextRange> FindTextInRange(TextPointer contentStart, TextPointer contentEnd, string searchText)
    {
        List<TextRange> results = new List<TextRange>();
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset >= 0)
        {
            var searchRange = new TextRange(contentStart, contentEnd);
            offset = searchRange.Text.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (offset < 0)
                break;  // Not found

            var start = GetTextPositionAtOffset(searchRange.Start, offset);
            TextRange result = new TextRange(start, GetTextPositionAtOffset(start, searchText.Length));
            contentStart = GetTextPositionAtOffset(start, searchText.Length);
            results.Add(result);
        }
        return results;
    }

    TextPointer GetTextPositionAtOffset(TextPointer position, int characterCount)
    {
        while (position != null)
        {
            if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
            {
                int count = position.GetTextRunLength(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                if (characterCount <= count)
                {
                    return position.GetPositionAtOffset(characterCount);
                }

                characterCount -= count;
            }

            TextPointer nextContextPosition = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (nextContextPosition == null)
                return position;

            position = nextContextPosition;
        }

        return position;
    }
```

Comment: I found a way  “  Rect r = textPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Backward);
rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(r.Y);  ”

Comment: var characterRect = textPointer.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward);
RichTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(RichTextBox.HorizontalOffset + characterRect.Left - RichTextBox.ActualWidth / 2d);
RichTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(RichTextBox.VerticalOffset + characterRect.Top - RichTextBox.ActualHeight / 2d);